# Is possible integrate WAS 9 and WSRR 8.5.6.2?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-9, wsrr

Is compatibilite Websphere Service Registry and Repositority (WSRR) 8.5.6.2 with Websphere Application Server 9 ?

Comment: please be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

The latest software compatibility report available says No: [https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=CAF6DB10A58011E496AA0BC59742B3EB&osPlatforms=AIX|Linux|Solaris|Windows|z/OS&duComponentIds=S000&mandatoryCapIds=30|13&optionalCapIds=66|9|71|121|74|27|69|26](https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=CAF6DB10A58011E496AA0BC59742B3EB&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CSolaris%7CWindows%7Cz/OS&duComponentIds=S000&mandatoryCapIds=30%7C13&optionalCapIds=66%7C9%7C71%7C121%7C74%7C27%7C69%7C26)

But this is really a question for the vendor, not stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everything covener,

I consulted that with the IBM Lab and effectively the answer was there is NO compatibility between WSRR V8.5.6.2 and WAS V9.

WSRR 8.5 is linked to WAS 8.5.5. Any fix pack to WSRR 8.5 will be supported by WAS 8.5.5 nothing else.

There are no plans to support WAS 9 by WSRR.